# Entrust permission in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.0. I am using Entrust for user permissions.
When I try to do the following function

```
Entrust::can('customers-views')
```

I am getting error like this. What is the reason for this. How can I solve this?

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Entrust' not found
```

Can I use Entrust:can function in controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try doing

`\Entrust::can('customers-views')`

or add the `use path\to\Entrust` line at the top of your file.